# OpenGL core profile not available despite glxinfo asserting is available

Tags: c, opengl, freebsd, glfw

I'm running: FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE and I have a ThinkPad x230 which I think it has an Intel HD 4000 GPU. I'm trying to run GLSL 4.20 with the core profile. When I run my program (written in C) I get:

```
Error - 0:1(10): error: GLSL 4.20 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

However if I run the `glxinfo` command I get (among other information) this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility,
    ...
```

I've trimmed the above output as it is very extense. Moreover this Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology) also asserts that OpenGL 4.20 is indeed supported by the GPU (though it refers only to GNU/Linux and Windows platforms). So I'm really puzzled if OpenGL 4.20 is supported or not in my system. Am I missing something or `glxinfo` is not being accurate?

Also when I run `glxgears -info` I get (full output also trimmed):

```
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
GL_VENDOR     = Intel Open Source Technology Center
...
```

And then if I set `#version 300 core` both in my vertex and fragment shaders the same error pops up:

```
Error - 0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.00 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

This error pops up when I'm compiling my shaders in the program. I'm using OpenGL through `GLFW3` with `GLAD` set to OpenGL version 4.20 and core profile from [here](https://glad.dav1d.de/). Any suggestions are more than welcome.

I'm editing my question adding the initialization code that I'm running:

```c
struct GameContext* new_game_context(size_t width, size_t height) {
    printf("[GameContext] new_game_context.\n");
    struct GameContext* game_context = calloc(1, sizeof(struct GameContext));

    abort_on(&null_pointer, (void*) game_context, GAME_CONTEXT_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY);

    game_context->keyboard = new_keyboard();
    game_context->window = 0;
    game_context->quit_game = false;

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    game_context->window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Test", 0, 0);

    abort_on(&null_pointer, (void*) game_context->window, GAME_CONTEXT_GLFW_WINDOW_ERROR);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(game_context->window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress))
        abort_on(&always, NULL, GAME_CONTEXT_GLAD_ERROR);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glLineWidth(GAME_CONTEXT_LINE_WIDTH);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(game_context->window, (GLFWkeyfun) handle_keyboard_event);
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(game_context->window, (void*) game_context->keyboard);

    game_context->game_objects = create_game_objects();

    return game_context;
}
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  For all we know you didn't request a Core context.  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.

Comment: This says GLSL 4.2 is not supported *in your current profile*. If your current profile is old, you might not be able to put new shaders in an old profile!

Comment: What does glGetString(GL_VERSION) return in your program?

Comment: @user253751 Is giving me: `3.0 Mesa 19.0.8`. So what you're saying is that I'm missing telling OpenGL that I want to use its 3.0 version through hints?

Comment: Try using [`glfwWindowHint`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga7d9c8c62384b1e2821c4dc48952d2033) to set the [major](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#gafe5e4922de1f9932d7e9849bb053b0c0)/[minor](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga31aca791e4b538c4e4a771eb95cc2d07) context version and [profile](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE_hint).  Otherwise you'll just get the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesa's generally going to give you a GL 2.1 or 3.0 context unless you ask for something higher.

Use `glfwWindowHint()` before `glfwCreateWindow()` to set the GL version and Core-ness to request:

```
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That was indeed the issue. What I still don't understand from OpenGL is why this information (the version) is both needed through a hint and also specified in the shaders. I mistakenly thought that specifying the profile version in the shaders was enough.

Comment: You can supply lower-than-current-version GLSL programs, like `#version 130` on a GL 4.2 context.  Basically just tells GL which parser & feature-set to use.